# Javascript add xml data to a UL list

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a query I have some xml data on a response variable.

The data looks like this:

```
<list type="cat">
  <instance id="4" name="somename" />
  <instance id="7" name="someo_there_name" />
</list>
```

I also have a UL prepared where I need a list with id and names appended into the ul

```
<ul id="thelist"></ul>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `map()` to iterate through the `instance` nodes, then addthe HTML which contains the `li` elements to the resulting array, before appending it all to the `ul`. Try this:

```js
var xml = '<list type="cat"><instance id="4" name="somename" /><instance id="7" name="someo_there_name" /></list>';

var html = $(xml).find('instance').map(function(){
  return `<li id=${$(this).attr('id')}">${$(this).attr('name')}</li>`;
}).get();
$('#thelist').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="thelist"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JQuery object from that XML data and then loop over to each `instance` element to create a list with `<li>` and then add that as a HTML to `<ul>` with `id="thelist"`.

```js
var xmlData = `<list type="cat">
  <instance id="4" name="somename" />
  <instance id="7" name="someo_there_name" />
</list>`;

var $xmlData = $(xmlData);
var nHTML = '';
$xmlData.find('instance').each(function(){
  nHTML+='<li id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'">'+$(this).attr('name')+'</li>';
});

$('#thelist').html(nHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="thelist"></ul>
```

For further verification, you can use browser's inspect element on that `<li>` elements and view the `id` values for each `<li>`